# How to delete element from a webpage with selenium using python3

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I have a problem with cookie popup at the end of a page which obscures my .click() method. I am wondering is there any way of bypassing this exception, somehow to delete the element, or just to make it unvisible. 
I have tried with scrolling down a page but it doesn't help. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try browser.execute_script.

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement())
```